# Bubblesort algorithm questions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have this question that I am very confused about, have been working on it for a while and I cannot seem to find any assistance.

```
input a: array [1 .. n] of integer; n : integer;
temp  i, j : integer;
j <-- n;
while j ≥ 1
    do   I <-- 1;
        while   i ˂ j
            do
                if  a[i] ˃ a[j]  then swap a[i], a[j];
                i <-- i + 1;
            od;
        j < j – 1;
    od
```

1. Will this algorithm terminate?

   I have my answer as no becayse a[i] and a[j] would never swap.
2. What is the worst case time complexity of this algorithm in O-notation as a function of the size of the sorting problem?
3. The precondition of this algorithm is the truth value TRUE.  The desired postcondition of the algorithm is:  `for i ˂ j, a[i] ˂ a[j], for i = 1, 2, . . . , n-1,  j = 2, . . . , n`

Find the two loop invariants for the inner and outer loops which you believe will lead to the desired postcondition if and when the  algorithm terminates.

Any help would be appreciated! I want to understand this!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you reading this first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

About your questions.

1) Yes, algorithm will definitely terminate. It will do double loop and finish.

2) The worst complexity is O(n^2).

3) Study and write it down: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant. SO won't do your entire homework.